# Blogger post with embedded YouTube video, linked and playable on facebook

Tags: facebook, blogger, embedded-video

On a blogger styled blog, where 1 day I might have an image in a blog post, and the next day have a YouTube video, is it possible, when linking the blog posts to facebook, to have facebook find and post the video the same way it finds the images on blog post?

I've seen other people talk about the "meta tags":

```
    <meta name="og:type" content="video"> // This is important so that OP will recognize your site as video streaming site like YouTube & Vimeo 
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"> // Don't Change this
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="Width in Pixels"> // player Width
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="Height in Pixels"> // Player Height
    <meta property="og:video" content="mySWFVideoPlayer.swf?url=Video_Soure"> // You will need to echo/print the Video Source (I.E. *.mp4) with a help of PHP or whatever your server uses
```

but meta tags are only used in the  of the blog/webpage, so this means I would only be able to setup 1 video for the whole blog, but I would like to use the videos embedded in each post (if there was a video embedded)

Answer (score 0):

For YouTube video embedded try this . This might be helping you in some way . Meta tag is very useful in this way .

```
<meta name='og:title' content='Big Buck Bunny'/>
<meta name='og:type' content='movie' />
<meta name='og:url' content='http://testsite.com/testfile.html' /> //Your html meta tag file path
<meta name='og:image' content='http://testsite.com/image.jpg' /> //Your image path
<meta name='og:site_name' content='TestSITE'>
<meta name='og:description' content='Big Buck Bunny is a short animated film by the Blender Institute, part of the Blender Foundation.'/>
<meta property='og:video' content='http://testsite.com/jwplayer/player.swf?file=video.mp4' /> //Your video path with player
<meta property='og:video:height' content='640'>
<meta property='og:video:width' content='385'>
<meta property='og:video:type' content='application/x-shockwave-flash' />
<meta property='og:video' content='http://testsite.com/video.mp4' /> //Your Video
<meta property='og:video:type' content='video/mp4' /> //Your Video Type for Mobile
<meta property='og:video:type' content='text/html' /> //Video type for other
```

Comment: The meta tags work but only for the global webpage, and specifically for blogger, I only know how to update the root website's header.  So if I used this code, every time I linked a new blog post is would always reference the same video (not the new video in each blog post) and facebook rejects meta tags that are not in the <head>